# how to find memory leak using Xcode's "Leaks?"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, memory

I check my pet project for possible memory leaks and they are displayed in the form of inscriptions "malloc 64/32 bytes"

You can see example in the picture:

[image]

I can't understand where I have to look for leaks in my code.

Comment: If you don’t see your code listed in the stack trace (to the right), these are exceedingly hard to diagnose. When I search for “NSXPCConnection remoteObjectProxyWithErrorHandler leak”, I see some SpriteKit references. Are you using SpriteKit?

Comment: Smells like a false positive to me. If you are determined to diagnose these 64 bytes, create [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (i.e., copy your project and start ripping out everything and see what is the bare minimum to manifest this problem) and then edit your question to include that.

Comment: The Xcode tab, Open Developer Tool -> Leaks -> Persistent/Total Bytes, try it to find something.